# Adding Spinner in info window of marker in google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, spinner, infowindow

I want to add A spinner in custom Info Window of my marker, All things are done and Spinner is displayed there but when I click on that spinner, No response!!!!.

So What can be done so that one can click on the spinner and select an item from it.

My Layout of Info Window is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_info_bubble"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google Documentation:

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

Then, you don't able to handle the spinner click but only if infowindow is clicked.

Comment: So what can be done if on some location I want a spinner on top of it to display various items based on that location, and it has to be displayed on the Map.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't interact with your spinner if you insert it into your infowindow.